# Is there a single USB wifi adapter/dongle which works on Ventura?

Tags: macos, network, wifi, usb, ventura

I'm struggling to shop for USB-based Wireless hardware to work with macOS. I ordered and sent back 2 USB dongles because they were mislabeled as compatible but don't want to list them here.

The closest I have come was TP-Link telling me to downgrade to Mojave (2018!!) to get the "Archer" to work but I can't entertain that old of a macOS on my computer.

Has anyone experienced using macOS Ventura and a USB wifi adapter working?

Comment: What Mac are using this with? Every Mac has had Wifi built-in for decades -- except some early Mac Pros, so I imagine that demand for Mac-compatible dongles is low.

Comment: I don’t think it’s a Ventura thing inasmuch as being an Intel vs. Silicon thing (lack of native drivers).  I’ve plugged in Broadcom based WiFi adapters into various Intel Macs with no problem.  I haven’t tried this with Silicon (yet).

Comment: @benwiggy MBP 15" latest. Its a complex use case but I cannot use the built in wifi

Comment: @Allan thats good to know & makes sense. I did find a chinese github project which seemed to do something but it was abandoned by the looks of it

Answer (score 0):

If you're Mac is Intel or you are building a hackintosh you can try this:
https://github.com/chris1111/Wireless-USB-Big-Sur-Adapter

It supports various Realtek 802.11n and 802.11ac USB Wi-Fi adapters, see the link for the full list. Works with macOS Sonoma 14, macOS Ventura 13, macOS Monterey 12, macOS Big Sur 11, and macOS Catalina 10.15.

However if you have an Apple Silicon/arm/M1/M2/M3 based Mac then it does not appear there is any solution at this time.